# How do you project points from a quadrilateral-faced hexahedron onto an axis-aligned cuboid that encompasses it?

Tags: matrices, 3d, computational-geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry

I'm using an r-tree to store axis-aligned cuboids for efficient querying. Currently, the comparison algorithms only allow you to use other axis-aligned cuboids (represented by $\min(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, $\max(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ for example) as an input.

I'd like to be able to query the r-tree (EDIT: for overlapping, containment, etc.) with *any* quadrilateral-faced hexahedron. My idea is to:

- Create an axis-aligned cuboid that encompasses the space by finding the minimum and maximum of the vertices' dimensions.
- Query the r-tree with that, generate results.
- **Generate a spatial transformation from the original quad-faced hexahedron to the encompassing cuboid.**
- Apply that transformation to the points of cuboid query results, and then query that set with the encompassing cuboid.
- All final results should be as if I queried the original r-tree with the quad-faced hexahedron.

The third step is what I'm having a little difficulty with. I assume it'll be a $4\times4$ matrix to transform the points in the space of the hexahedron to the cuboid- there's a lot of literature on projection matrices to get from frustum to cube for screen space transformations that do something similar.

So the question is- what's the easiest way to get my points from quad-faced hexahedron space to an encompassing, axis-aligned cuboid space?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hmm, what I'm trying to say is "any arbitrary polyhedra with the polyhedral graph of a cube". Is there a better way of saying that?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You have an hexahedron in general position (I mean with a unique vertex with minimal x (or y, or z) min. and max. coordinates (in order to avoid particular cases, such as an horizontal edge), and you want to have a **central projection** (but how do you choose the center ?) from this hexahedron to the smallest cuboid with edges parallel to the axis coordiantes.

Comment: Seems like what you’re trying to do is map an arbitrary hex to a cube. I don’t know how to do that, but it might be useful to study the 2D quad-to-rectangle problem, for starters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190483/transform-quadrilateral-into-a-rectangle

Comment: @JeanMarie Yep, that's it! General position is a good term to remember, thanks for that.

Comment: @bubba That's precisely it, just extended to 3 dimensions. I'll start working with that in mind.

Comment: When you say "any arbitrary polyhedra with the polyhedral graph of a cube", say with vertices ABCDEFGH, do you implicitly mean that the vertices of a given quadrilateral say ABCD belong to a same plane (i.e. are co-planar) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Don't they have to be coplanar by definition, at least in Euclidean space?